# How to create the file from the embedded source to the user specified location?

Tags: c#, reflection, nlog

I have embedded as resource an nlog config file . 
I am trying to create log files in to the user specified location. 
But the Nlog requires the nlog config file to be present into the user specified location. 
So I thought of creating the nlog config files to the user specified location , before it starts writing the log files. 
So For this I have embedded as resource an nlog config file . but my problem is now how to write the write this embedded source into the location where the user specifies . 
I am posting my the code i have come up with

```
Assembly _assembly;
Stream _config;
// StreamReader _textStreamReader;
try
{
        _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        _config = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XXX.NLog.config");
        // _textStreamReader = new  StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XXX.NLog.config"));

        using (Stream output = File.Open(config.LogFileFolder, FileMode.Create))
        {
               byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
               int len;
               while ((len = _config.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
               {
                      output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
               }
         }

}
catch
{
        MessageBox.Show("Error accessing resources!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *StreamReader* and *StreamWriter*.

Example:

```
    using (StreamReader reader =
        new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(defaultContentResourceName)))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(targetPath))
        {
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```